# Should I include a job on my resume that is indirectly relevant to my skill set?

Tags: resume

I am a veteran in the technology realm looking to get closer to the customer (as opposed to behind the keyboard all the time). I have spent quite a bit of time refining my already lengthy resume to highlight my customer interactions, and every bullet point resolves to a tangible and measurable achievement. I am also currently moonlighting as a fitness instructor, and have been doing so for 3 years.

I (personally) believe this is relevant because it shows leadership and direct interaction with "customers". It also highlights my ability to transfer information to people who may be less knowledgeable.

- It would make my printed resume 3 pages
- If I were to keep it chronological and under "Experience", it would be at/near the top

[This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/incorporating-off-job-technical-qualifications-on-resume) post suggests an "Other Relevant Experience" section, which to me sounds gratuitous for just one additional title... one could argue that I could add at least one more, or perhaps move my freelance work there as well, but I'm still at 3 pages.

Your angle on this is appreciated.

Comment: How old are you? If you are 25 with a 3 page resume that's a lot different than if you are 50.

Comment: What all is in your resume that makes it 3 pages?  Most places I've seen for resume advice suggest 1-2 pages for a resume.  The rest can be discussed in an interview.

Comment: @enderland I am 30 years old and I have been a legitimate professional for 13 years.

Comment: @JBKing My career has mostly been composed of consultant work; 12-18 month projects. Over 13 years, that ends up being a lot of employers and projects.

Comment: Specifically speaking to being a fitness instructor, it is more directly relevant to working with customers in the technology field than you are giving it credit for.

Comment: @GregMcNulty Actually, I believe I am holding it in a well-deserved high regard, which is why I wrote this post in the first place. I have always thought of it as an extremely valuable asset to my career and I didn't know how to best convey it. In tech, most people are either technical experts (who don't know how to talk to people), or very informed salespeople (who don't know how to code). My experience as a fitness instructor combined with my deep technological background should convey that I am both.

Comment: Include you experience as a fitness instructor, is something you did and tells stuff about you. Add it, "relevant" is kind of a nonsense concept here. Reading SE sometimes seems to me that users forget the companies hire people not machines, just for e.g. in my last two hiring process we spent much time talking about how I fly gliders....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types of positions being applied for should drive the content of your cover letter and resume. There may be customer facing positions that don't require any of the technical background you have, but you more than likely are a better fit for those that do. It's important to show that dual-role you're able to play.

The personal training experience may be more relevant, so don't hide it in the "other" section and focus on it in the cover-letter. Help the hiring person make this connection right away.

If you have a lengthy list of experiences, you don't have to list them all. Just make sure you don't leave any gaps for the last 10 years.

Comment: In the cover letter! Thats brilliant! Perfect advice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is conflicting advice about how far back you should go in your resume, but the last 10 years sounds right. If you're working with a recruiting firm, you can give them a long resume, and they will edit it to fit the employer.

Add the information that will demonstrate the breadth of your skills including your leadership and people skills. Volunteer work would also be appropriate.

Don't list skills that you don't want to use, or are archaic, like COBOL or FORTRAN, unless that is what you want to do.