# Is it a good idea to include warehouse general worker skills for an IT job?

Tags: software-industry, resume, skills, customer-service

Is it a good idea to mention warehouse general worker skills on a resume for an IT job such as computer technician when you don't have any job experience in IT field or I should avoid mentioning that and instead, highlight my good academic record. I'm quite worried.

If you were an employer hiring a person for a computer technician job whose main job will be to interact with customers, how will you find my job description below? Thanks a lot for the help!

The things I did in warehouse:
1) Loading and unloading stuff from containers.
2) Group leadership right on second shift
3) Paperwork related to items loaded/unloaded
4) Excellent communication with supervisor and group members

Any suggestions to rewrite above skills will be welcomed.

Comment: Did you hold a job at the same place for an extended period of time? If so, list it, with dates. On the other hand, given the lack of IT or customer interaction content, I would not go into any detail.

Comment: It's evidence you could hold a job,  show up on time, and work with others. Since you don't have any professional experience, it's better than nothing. But since it says nothing about whether you can do _this_ in, I agree that you should keep it brief and let the interviewer ask questions if they want to know more.

Comment: Are you fresh out of University? Was this a part-time job to finance your studies? It would show that you are organized enough to manage both at the same time and responsible. Still, don't put too much emphasis on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/should-i-include-a-job-on-my-resume-that-is-indirectly-relevant-to-my-skill-set?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When applying for a job, you'll want to include the best experience you have for that job, preferably in order of importance.

Relevant work experience would go first, an education in the field would go second, probably personal projects in the field go third, but if there's still room you could put in work experience in other fields after that. You want to keep it not too long, probably limited to 3 or so major items, but if all you've got to bring is experience as a warehouse worker, I would add it.

At least it shows the company that you are able to keep a job, have the right attitude, and have basic experience with being a member of the workforce. That's still going to count for something.

Comment: The willingness to work and manage competing priorities is important in every job you will ever have.  Highlight those kinds of skills.